# ¿Cómo construir una vista con GROUP BY y varios campos?

Tags: mysql, group-by

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos de ciclismo.

Tengo que crear una vista PREMIOS que refleje todos los maillots llevados por los ciclistas y el premio económico obetenidos con los siguientes datos: nombre de ciclista, número de etapa y color de maillot.

Me funciona

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW  "VISTA1" ("NOMBRE", "TOTALMAILLOT") AS 
    select ciclista.NOMBRE,COUNT(llevar.dorsal) as TOTALMAILLOT from ciclista,llevar 
    where ciclista.dorsal=llevar.dorsal group by ciclista.nombre order by TOTALMAILLOT;

select nombre,totalmaillot from vista1;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al querer añadirle un campo más me da un fallo. Creo que es por el `group by` y que solo me deja poner el campo nombre que usamos para filtrar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pusetodo mayuscula para ser mas estricto, añadi en el from maillot y el join de las tablas maillot y llevar.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW  "VISTA1" ("NOMBRE", "TOTALMAILLOT","color") AS 
  SELECT CICLISTA.NOMBRE,COUNT(LLEVAR.DORSAL) AS TOTALMAILLOT,MAILLOT.COLOR FROM 
  CICLISTA,LLEVAR,MAILLOT
  WHERE CICLISTA.DORSAL=LLEVAR.DORSAL AND MAILLOT.CODIGO=LLEVAR.CODIGO GROUP BY 
  CICLISTA.NOMBRE ORDER BY TOTALMAILLOT;

  SELECT NOMBRE,TOTALMAILLOT,COLOR FROM VISTA1;
```

Comment: Tendrás que meter el nuevo campo en la clausula `group by`. Ademas, supongo que tendras que añadir `maillot` en el from y poner la condición del join.

Comment: `... maillot.color from ciclista, llevar...` por lo que parece la columna `color` debe ser extraída de una tabla llamada `maillot` la cual no aparece en ninguna parte, como tampoco aparece cómo ni con qué tabla se relacionará dicha tabla `maillot`... Por otra parte, te recomiendo que seas más estricto al escribir tu código: usas unos nombres de columna en mayúscula, otros en minúscula y lo mismo con las instrucciones SQL y con el nombre de la vista... decídete por uno o por otro.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, efectivamente hay una tabla maillot y no lo habia puesto en el from,pero sigo con la duda de como meter el campo maillot.color dentro del group by por que ahora tengo el campo ciclista.nombre.

Comment: Pues `GROUP BY 
  CICLISTA.NOMBRE,MAILLOT.COLOR` imagino

Comment: Para agregar color al GROUP BY: `GROUP BY 
  CICLISTA.NOMBRE, MAILLOT.COLOR` y para juntar las tablas yo usaría JOIN en vez de WHERE, ya que es más eficaz. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para agregar `MAILLOT.COLOR` al `GROUP BY`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW  "VISTA1" ("NOMBRE", "TOTALMAILLOT","color") AS 
  SELECT CICLISTA.NOMBRE,COUNT(LLEVAR.DORSAL) AS TOTALMAILLOT,MAILLOT.COLOR FROM 
  CICLISTA,LLEVAR,MAILLOT
  WHERE CICLISTA.DORSAL=LLEVAR.DORSAL AND MAILLOT.CODIGO=LLEVAR.CODIGO 
  GROUP BY CICLISTA.NOMBRE, MAILLOT.COLOR 
  ORDER BY TOTALMAILLOT;

  SELECT NOMBRE,TOTALMAILLOT,COLOR FROM VISTA1;
```

Aunque se recomienda usar `JOIN`en vez de `WHERE` para juntar tablas.

Algo así:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW  "VISTA1" ("NOMBRE", "TOTALMAILLOT","COLOR") AS 
SELECT CICLISTA.NOMBRE, COUNT(LLEVAR.DORSAL) AS TOTALMAILLOT, MAILLOT.COLOR
   FROM CICLISTA
   INNER JOIN LLEVAR  ON CICLISTA.DORSAL=LLEVAR.DORSAL 
   INNER JOIN MAILLOT ON LLEVAR.CODIGO=MAILLOT.CODIGO
   GROUP BY CICLISTA.NOMBRE, MAILLOT.COLOR 
   ORDER BY TOTALMAILLOT;

SELECT NOMBRE,TOTALMAILLOT,COLOR FROM VISTA1;
```

**PD:** También puedes pasar totalmente de la vista y usar el SELECT directamente... el código sería más eficaz.

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios , tenia entendido que solo se podia usar un campo en el group by voy a probar.

Comment: @DavidPalanco `GROUP BY ...` puede tener **varias columnas** separadas por coma, como indica el ejemplo.